# Remove navigation bar in contentpage Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigationbar

I am trying to remove navbar from my pages in Xamarin Forms, but I am not able to get it working. I have tried by adding NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false); inside constructor of page eg.

```
public RegisterUser ()
{           
    InitializeComponent ();
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
}
```

And / or by adding NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" inside xaml page

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="PetApp.Pages.RegisterUser"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false">
```

But none of those helps.

Is there some better best practice to just show clean page with scrollview or should it be possible to remove navbar totally?

It works in Mainpage but not the rest of pages that I am navigating to via

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new RegisterUser()));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution, instead of using Navigation.PushAsync I used

```
Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new RegisterPet()));
```

and also OnAppearing of RegisterPet page I added SetHasNavigationBar

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            InitializeSettings();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

            base.OnAppearing();
        }
```

Comment: Great idea. But for me in xf 4.8 after Navigation.PushModalAsync Navigation Bar wont appear anymore.